# Enabling archive engine

Tags: mysql, archive

How do I enable archive storage engine in MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is kind of late, as in 2 years, but I found this question via Google so thought I'd add an answer which worked for me with mysql v5.1.56

Assuming that the archive plugin is available (see if it is in the plugin directory which is /lib/mysql/plugin on my dist) it can be enabled via the mysql shell using:

install plugin soname "so_archive.so";

Enter "archive" as the single entry on a line in my.cnf (often in /etc).

Restart the mysql daemon

That should be it, the command "show engines" should now show the archive engine as being available.

BTW. I found that tables cannot be converted to use the archive engine unless all the indexes are removed first, if that is not done a "cannot create table" error is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/archive-storage-engine.html),

> The ARCHIVE storage engine is included
>   in MySQL binary distributions. To
>   enable this storage engine if you
>   build MySQL from source, invoke
>   configure with the
>   --with-archive-storage-engine option.

Are you building from source?  Are you using a distribution that's not a normal MySQL binary distribution?  Impossible to tell from your question, so that's the best we can do to help unless and until you clarify the exact details of you problem situation.

Comment: Somebody else has done the installation and I don't know much about it. The OS is centOS and mysql version 5.0